# Is it possible to make two SOCKSv4a session connections over one TCP connection?

Tags: sockets, tcp, proxy, protocols, socks

I'm trying to create multiple tunnels out of a single TCP connection to a SOCKSv4a proxy server in order to keep from closing and reopening a bunch of sockets to the SOCKS proxy.

Something like "Connection: keep-alive". How can I do that? Does the protocol allow it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not supported by any version of SOCKS (nor is it supported by HTTP/1.1 `CONNECT` method — `keep-alive` is ignored for `CONNECT`).  Once a tunnel is established, it is a straight pass-through of raw data until either the client or server disconnects.  You need to open a separate client-proxy connection for each new connection to the server.